# Laravel: get translation from language file containing dot

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

Is it possible to get translation from language file that contains (.)dot?

For example, The language directory looks like

```
/lang
      /en
          pagination.php
          phone.history.php

     /es
          pagination.php
          phone.history.php
```

phone.history.php file contains dot and want to get translation for the key 'name' from phone.history.php file.

```
Lang::get('phone.history.name')
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: why not use a sub directory as laravel intends?

Comment: @Emn1ty actually using dot notation for subdirectories doesn't work when loading translation files the same way it does for configuration files. You can only have one `.` in the translation key.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the Laravel key used for translations **can only contain one dot** `.` in order to work and the function of that dot is to separate the translation file path (relative to the language directory) from the translation array key. That's because the `Translator` class extends the `Illuminate\Support\NamespacedItemResolver` class, which [parses the key](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/NamespacedItemResolver.php#L20-L44) using the following logic:

- First it determines if there is a namespace present (denoted by `::`) and extracts it.
- It then goes on to split the key into a `group` (which is the relative filepath) and an `item` (which is the translation array key).

So in your case since there is no namespace, when you use this:

```
Lang::get('phone.history.name')
```

The result is the following:

- The filename will be `phone`
- The translation array key will be `history` (instead of `name`)

And since there's no `phone.php` in your language directory, it won't work.

---

So you have two options here:

1. Use another character in your filename so there's only one dot in the translator parameter, something like `/lang/en/phone_history.php` and then use `Lang::get('phone_history.name')`.
2. Use a subdirectory if you want to group some translation files, something like `/lang/en/phone/history.php` and then use `Lang::get('phone/history.name')` (unfortunately, as I said above you can only use one dot as a separator, so you can't use the multiple level dot notation as you would for a configuration file `Lang::get('phone.history.name')`).

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a 3rd option which is to use dotted key names. So inside `/lang/en/phone.php` you can set `'history.name' => 'John Doe'` and then retrieve that using `trans('phone.history.name')`.